# Working capture cards for Processing on a Mac

Tags: macos, processing, video-capture

I recently bought a USB capture card for my Mac (EzCap: [http://www.amazon.com/Easycap-Version-Capturer-Camcorder-Compatible/dp/B0044XIQIW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0044XIQIW)) and I'm not all that shocked to find out it doesn't work with Processing. (I've tried the Capture library and GSVideo).

My app needs to take in video from an external source (i.e not just the built in iSight camera - which is super simple) for processing.

I was wondering if anyone has a working video capture implementation? And could let me know what capture devices worked for them?

Thought i'd ask before I start wasting a tonne of time and money buying more expensive devices that also might not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start off by checking if your USB camera is seen in processing. Using GSVideo for example:

```
import codeanticode.gsvideo.*;
GSCapture cam;
void setup() {
size(640,480);
String[] cameras = GSCapture.list(); 
  if (cameras.length == 0)
  {
    println("There are no cameras available for capture.");
    exit();
  } else {
    println("Available cameras:");
    for (int i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
      println(cameras[i]);
    } }
cam = new GSCapture(this, 640, 480, cameras[0]);  
cam.start(); }
```

if it does see the camera, you can add the draw() function:

```
 void draw(){
    if (cam.available() == true) {
    cam.read();
    cam.loadPixels();  
    image(cam,0,0);
}}
```

That works for me.

Comment: The question is more about functional capture devices, not how to write the capture code.